Add three lines to make a Capital City
Add exactly three lines to the image below to make a capital city (note the tags):


Got it!

 

 By adding a horizontal line to the centre of each of the 3 'C' shapes, we end up with three E's, i.e. Triple E, or TRIPOLI (Libya)!


That was quick!!! Good job!!! You’re on a roll today!!!

@PDT Thanks - it was a moment of inspiration! I'd been thinking about combinations of C's, E's, G's and O's and ways to pronounce them to form city names before this possibility jumped out at me and made me laugh :)

funny story, my inspiration was actually from an internet username of someone from North Africa. When it struck me what his username pointed too I thought hmm this might make a good puzzle.
